# Find Row Lock using select * from V$SESSION where status='ACTIVE'

Tags: oracle

I'm unable to update a particular row (Using SQL Developer directly) in my database and I'm trying to figure out why.  The update just keeps going infinitely. I'm guessing a query has a lock on that particular row, but I'm unsure how to find out.  Any ideas?  When do a `select * from V$SESSION where status='ACTIVE'` I don't see any table name or query info.

**Blocking Session Query:**

```
  select blocking_instance,blocking_session from v$session where blocking_instance is not null
```

**Blocking Session Query Results:**

```
blocking_instance  blocking_session
1                  104
1                  104
1                  104
1                  104
1                  104
1                  144
1                  104
```

**SELECT * FROM dba_blockers**

```
holding_session
55
104
145
92
```

**SELECT * FROM dba_waiters**

```
waiting_session  holding_session  lock_type     mode_held  mode_requested lock_id1  lock_id2
144          55           Transaction   Exclusive  Exclusive      262163    1802
104          55           DML           Row-X (SX) S/Row-X (SSX)  24034     0
96           55           DML           Row-X (SX) Row-X (SX)     24034     0
94           92           Transaction   None       Exclusive      589835    1904
92           92           Transaction   None       Exclusive      589835    1904
104          104          DML           Row-X (SX) S/Row-X (SSX)  24034     0
96           104          DML           Row-X (SX) Row-X (SX)     24034     0
94           145          Transaction   Exclusive  Exclusive      589835    1904
92           145          Transaction   Exclusive  Exclusive      589835    1904
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have session 1 that holds the lock, session 2 that is waiting on the lock, and session 3 where you can run queries to diagnose the problem,

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_blockers

SELECT *
  FROM dba_waiters
```

will show you which sessions are blocking other sessions and which sessions are blocked by other sessions along with the type of lock.  That will allow you to determine that session 1 is blocking session 2.

In `v$session`, the `blocking_session` for session 2 would also indicate that it was blocked by session 1.

Comment: I ran these two queries and posted the results above in my question.  Based on these results it seems that I should kill 55, 104, 145 and 92.  Agree?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention a version of Oracle, but, if it's reasonably recent, you could do something like:

```
select blocking_instance,blocking_session from v$session where sid = <sid of session that is stuck hanging>;
```

Hope that helps....

Comment: so I should kill any session that doesn't have a null blocking_instance and blocking_session?  I don't know which session is the one that is stuck

Comment: @c12 - A session that has values in `blocking_instance` and `blocking_session` is the session that is being blocked.  You could, I suppose, kill that session.  But you would normally be more interested in the blocker not the blockee (and blindly killing things without figuring out why it is holding the lock seems short-sighted).

Comment: @JustinCave what about the edit I just made.  Shouldn't the results of that query give me the sessions that are causing the row lock?

Comment: @c12 - Do you have some reason to believe that the query you posted doesn't give you that (assuming that the session causing the row lock is defined to be the holder of the lock rather than the requestor)?  The script you posted looks to be rather dated-- I'd much rather use the `blocking_session` in `v$session` or the data in `dba_waiters` or `dba_blockers` unless you're dealing with a really old version of Oracle where those columns/ objects don't exist.

Comment: @JustinCave I'm using 11g so that those should be fine.  
select * from v$session where blocking_session is not null seems to return what I'm looking for

Comment: @c12 - That gives you the sessions that are being blocked.  The `blocking_session`, `blocking_instance` give you the holders of the locks.

Comment: @JustinCave - ok I updated my initial question with the results of the select blocking_instance,blocking_session from v$session where blocking_instance is not null query